# Send from email address

Tags: magento2, email, magento-2.1.9

I added a second domain to my web server. I had my hosting company assist with postfix configuration. Since then I am able to send email from the  command line using php:

```
php -r 'mail("destination@mycompany.tld", "Test Subject", "Test Message", "-f sales@secondarywebsite.tld");'
```

When I use the above to send email to either Outlook and Gmail, everything is perfect, so long as I include the `"-f sales@secondarywebsite.tld"`. Email from Magento, on the other hand, shows me the email is "sent by/via" `sales=secondarywebsite.tld@mainwebsite.tld`.

Since as far as I know Magento is using the php mail command, why am I not getting the correct from address? What can I do to fix this? This seems like it would be a very common problem to have, I would think there is some sort of setting in Magento I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I take it from the lack of response this probably isn't possible to do with standalone Magento.

In order to send from the correct domain, I made a plugin using [this WebKul tutorial](https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-mail-using-your-smtp-detail/) as suggested in a similar question.

The [complete module](https://github.com/jbokhari/Magetrix_Smtp/) goes a bit beyond the tutorial by creating a settings page in Magento where you can enter smtp info.

[image]